# How to get/pass current ScreenManager to button callback function? (no kv file in use)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Question is simple. I have ScreenManager as sm variable, how do I get that, and screen information in to button callback. Thank you already for possible solutions.

Below is the issue part of my code, I have commented the section that I need to solve:

```
def build(self):
    def callback_home(dt):
        # How do I get the current sreenmanager here so
        # things would work as below
        sm.switch_to(screen1, direction='left')

    app = FloatLayout()

    # Ui top
    anchor_top = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='top')
    app.add_widget(anchor_top)

    box_top = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                        size_hint=(1.0, 0.1))
    anchor_top.add_widget(box_top)

    btn_home = Button(text='Home')
    btn_home.bind(on_press=callback_home) #Callback line is in here
    btn_add = Button(text='Add')
    btn_upload = Button(text='Upload')

    box_top.add_widget(btn_home)
    box_top.add_widget(btn_add)
    box_top.add_widget(btn_upload)

    # Ui bottom
    anchor_bottom = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='bottom')
    app.add_widget(anchor_bottom)

    sm = ScreenManager(size_hint=(1.0, 0.9))
    anchor_bottom.add_widget(sm)

    screen1 = Screen(name='Home')
    screen1.add_widget(Label(text='Home'))
    sm.add_widget(screen1)
    screen2 = Screen(name='Add')
    screen2.add_widget(Label(text='Add'))
    sm.add_widget(screen2)
    screen3 = Screen(name='Upload')
    screen3.add_widget(Label(text='Upload'))
    sm.add_widget(screen3)
    return app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your callback function after your create the `ScreenManager`. But this is 10 times easier if you use kv language.

Also - `ScreenManager.switch_to()` only works with new `Screen`s. Using this method to switch to a `Screen` which has already been added to a `ScreenManager` will throw an `Exception`.

Finally, your layout can be much simpler if you use a `BoxLayout` instead of a `FloatLayout` and `AnchorLayout`s.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        Button:
            text: 'Home' 
            on_press: sm.current = 'Home'
        Button:
            text: 'Add'
            on_press: sm.current = 'Add'
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        Screen:
            name: 'Home'
            Label:
                text: 'Home'
        Screen:
            name: 'Add'
            Label:
                text: 'Add'
```